# Android Webview disable all links but enable scroll

Tags: android, webview, scrollbar, hyperlink

I am using Webview in android where i load a webpage but, I want all the links to be disabled and web view should be scrollable.

I am using the following code right now:

```
tnc.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        return true;
                     }
                 });
```

This makes web view disabled but scrolling also goes away.

I have also tried :

```
tnc.setClickable(false);
```

but this also doe not work. Please help me out.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to override the clicking of links in the `WebView`, you can use the [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideKeyEvent%28android.webkit.WebView%2C%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) method of the [`WebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html).

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is loading the url within the web view itself. nut i want that it should not navigate at all.

Comment: I tried your code. The links are not opening a new page but if there is a button then its redirecting on other page. I want that no interaction should be possible with web view except scrolling

Comment: I do not understand the point in disabling user interaction in a WebView with interactive elements. However, you could achieve what you want with implementing the shouldOverrideKeyEvent as well or using a layout where the WebView is below a transparent overlay view element which receives all the touch events. You could then have both the overlay as well as the WebView in a ScrollView.

Comment: Didn't work for me! seems like there is some problem with shouldOverrideUrlLoading method as it works for emulator but not for real device. And also there might be some issue with it as this method is override now

Answer (score 0):

simply add this to your webview in layout
`android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`